# Update the ListView Item based on Spinner selection in android

Tags: android, android-listview, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

Currently am working on listview with spinner.MY requirement is update the listview item based on spinner selection which is in listview item itself.but while performing the selection in spinner it update the all listview items.I think my problem is with in

> OnItemSelectedListener

.And also i figure out while loading listview the spinner ItemSelectedListener executes no of times.I don't understand want i have done on this.Please help me to find the solution for it.

Spinner OnItemSelected Listener code is

```
    viewHolder.description.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                //here the position represents the listview item position
                Log.e("Position of Data is ", Integer.toString(position));
                //here the fullListData.get(pos) get the data from spinner based on selection 
                datas.set(position, fullSeatList.get(pos));
               //here am update the listview item data with selected spinner data
                datas.get(position).getDescription());
                Log.e("Data in lisr", datas.get(position).getPartNo());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

EDIT 1:
My Adapter class is

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<SeatConfigCustomObjects> datas;
ArrayList<SeatConfigCustomObjects> fullSeatList;
ArrayAdapter<SeatConfigCustomObjects> adapter;
public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SeatConfigCustomObjects> datas, ArrayList<SeatConfigCustomObjects> fullSeatList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.datas = datas;
    this.fullSeatList=fullSeatList;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return datas.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return datas.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView=((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.seat_config_listview_item,null);
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.partNo=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seat_config_listview_partno);
        viewHolder.description=(Spinner)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seat_config_listview_description_spinner);
        viewHolder.quantity=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seat_config_listview_quantity);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.partNo.setText(datas.get(position).getPartNo());
     adapter=new ArrayAdapter<SeatConfigCustomObjects>(context,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,fullSeatList);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    viewHolder.description.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewHolder.description.setSelection(0, false);
    viewHolder.description.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Log.e("Position of Data is ", Integer.toString(position));
                datas.set(position, fullSeatList.get(pos));
                Log.e("Data in description", datas.get(position).getDescription());
                Log.e("Data in lisr", datas.get(position).getPartNo());
                notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    viewHolder.quantity.setText(Integer.toString(datas.get(position).getQunatity()));

    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder{
    TextView partNo;
    Spinner description;
    TextView quantity;

}
```

}

Comment: Are you receive any errors..

Comment: try listAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged.

Comment: i used base adapter for listview

Comment: @ArunShankar i used notifydatasetChanged inside the setOnItemSelectedListener.

Comment: @Vishwa didn't receive any errors.

Comment: are you updating  arraylist in your adapter..?

Comment: But I do not see it in code you posted... `notifyDataSetChanged();` will notify to refresh the listview but  with same arraylist...you have to update you array list in your adater too....

Comment: Can you post your adapter clas

Comment: Yes, @Mohit is correct. 
I dont think that you have used the 'notifyDataSetChanged();' correctly. 
notifyDataSetChanged(); will only refresh the listview when add(), insert(), remove() and clear() are done on the adapter.

Comment: @Mohit i updated with adapter class

Comment: Try updating your code in the UI thread.
Example:
`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});`

Comment: why does your Adapter make use of two ArrayLists?

Comment: that code update the UI but it updates all views and it doesn't stop.Updating all items without break;If you run that code you will get the Log message rapidly...

Comment: @0X0nosugar one ArrayList for user Selected data and another  one for predefined list for spinner

Answer (score 0):

Make your array-list public (*to access it from main class*) in base adapter class then add `String` to list on button click,and call `notifyDataSetChanged();` I have shown it below .Please change variable according to your convenience...

```
viewHolder.description.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
       ListViewAdapter <object>;   //Adapter class object
       <object>.datas.add("");  //-----string,position---//
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Adapter class :

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  public ArrayList<SeatConfigCustomObjects> datas;
  //-- rest of code--- ///
}
```